# (Http-01): urn: ietf: params: acme: error: unauthorized error when I execute "$ sudo certbot renew --dry-run" command

Tags: nginx, centos7, lets-encrypt, nginx-config, certbot

**environment** ・Nginx ・ CentOS 7 ・ Certbot 0.31.0

---

> $ sudo certbot renew --dry-run

---

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log


Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/hoge.example.com.conf

Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for hoge.example.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert (hoge.example.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/hoge.example.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. hoge.example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from https://hoge.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxx [IP address]: "<!doctype html>\r\n<html lang=\"ja\">\r\n<head>\r\n\t<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\r\n\t<meta http-e". Skipping.
```

---

**Question**

・What exactly does a Failed authorization procedure mean?

・Error contents are cut off in Skipping. What should I do to display them all?

---

**2019/4/16 add**

> $ sudo less /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

```
2019-04-16 20:40:54,333:DEBUG:certbot.updater:Skipping renewal deployer in dry-run mode.
2019-04-16 20:40:55,401:DEBUG:certbot.updater:Skipping updaters in dry-run mode.
2019-04-16 20:40:55,455:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var dry_run=True (set by user).
2019-04-16 20:40:55,455:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var server=set(['staging', 'dry_run']) (set by user).
2019-04-16 20:40:55,456:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var dry_run=True (set by user).
2019-04-16 20:40:55,456:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var server=set(['staging', 'dry_run']) (set by user).
2019-04-16 20:40:55,456:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var account=set(['server']) (set by user).
2019-04-16 20:40:55,482:DEBUG:certbot.storage:Should renew, less than 30 days before certificate expiry 2019-05-01 22:55:56 UTC.
2019-04-16 20:40:55,482:INFO:certbot.renewal:Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
2019-04-16 20:40:55,482:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator manual and installer None
2019-04-16 20:40:55,483:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.disco:Other error:(PluginEntryPoint#manual): An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 132, in prepare
    self._initialized.prepare()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/plugins/manual.py", line 133, in prepare
    self.option_name('auth-hook')))
PluginError: An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.
2019-04-16 20:40:55,516:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:No candidate plugin
2019-04-16 20:40:55,516:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Selected authenticator None and installer None
2019-04-16 20:40:55,516:INFO:certbot.main:Could not choose appropriate plugin: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.',)
2019-04-16 20:40:55,520:WARNING:certbot.renewal:Attempting to renew cert (example.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf produced an unexpected error: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.',). Skipping.
2019-04-16 20:40:55,527:DEBUG:certbot.renewal:Traceback was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 452, in handle_renewal_request
    main.renew_cert(lineage_config, plugins, renewal_candidate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1187, in renew_cert
    installer, auth = plug_sel.choose_configurator_plugins(config, plugins, "certonly")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 237, in choose_configurator_plugins
    diagnose_configurator_problem("authenticator", req_auth, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 341, in diagnose_configurator_problem
    raise errors.PluginSelectionError(msg)
PluginSelectionError: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.',)

2019-04-16 20:40:55,527:ERROR:certbot.renewal:The following certs could not be renewed:
2019-04-16 20:40:55,527:ERROR:certbot.renewal:  /etc/letsencrypt/live/entrepreneur.0mode.tokyo/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
2019-04-16 20:40:55,528:DEBUG:certbot.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.31.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1365, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1272, in renew
    renewal.handle_renewal_request(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 477, in handle_renewal_request
    len(renew_failures), len(parse_failures)))
```

Comment: What are the exact contents of `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log`?

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg.I add letsencrypt.log.

Comment: OK. That clarifies what the error is. You are not using the nginx plugin, but rather the manual plugin. See the changed answer below.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I read the answer and understood the cause. I remembered that I was trying to get a wildcard certificate. I would like to rewrite the configuration file to use the nginx plugin or choose to delete it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to renew the cert at `hoge.example.com`, which you almost certainly don't own. The letsencrypt nginx plugin will update your nginx configuration so that there is a server block that serves on port 80 (http) at the domain `hoge.example.com`. It will server a path at `.well-known/<some-hash>`. Then the letsencrypt server sends an HTTP request to `http://hoge.example.com/.well-known/<some-hash>`. This is failing since you don't actually own the domain.

You need to change your config so that you are creating a cert for the domain that you own.

---

**EDIT**: With the log, I know more information.

The key lines of the log are:

```
Requested authenticator manual and installer None
Other error:(PluginEntryPoint#manual): An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.
```

What this means is that you are not using the nginx plugin, but rather the [manual plugin](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual). And when you use the manual plugin, you need to specify an authorization hook, which is basically a way of proving that you own the website you say that you do. It's likely a problem with your config.

Here is what mine looks like:

```
# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.32.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-domain.net
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
installer = nginx
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
account = xxx123456789xxx
authenticator = nginx
```

Notice the *installer* and *authenticator* sections. Yours should look similar.

I would first recommend that you make sure that your config looks like mine and try again. If that doesn't work, you should probably just delete and recreate your cert.

Comment: I have replaced it with hoge.example.com to ask a question, but here I'm trying on my own domain.